# Google Cloud GPU all region quota increase request getting rejected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ai

I have created my Google cloud account and by default the GPU quota for all region is 0. So I have submitted multiple requests for quota increase but they haven’t approved even one. I tried contacting the sales stuff but even they rejected the request. Any way to get that request approved?
I have upgraded my account. 
Added billing details. 
Added 500 rs to account as a pay early option. 
Still have around 19,500 ₹ credits remaining.

Comment: Sorry for your problems, but how do you expect StackOverflow to approve your Google account? The only reason that I know of is that you do not have a valid credit card on file with sufficient credit available. Putting credits on your account will not solve that requirement.

Comment: *"even they rejected the request"*  Did they not provide a reason?

Comment: Nope. They said sales escalation is a good path for getting quota approval